# android mediaplayer error

Tags: android

i am trying to play a media file(mp4) using android mediaplayer but getting error as

"error(1, -2147483648)" ,i am able to play the same file from a url

Comment: I guess you'll have to be more specific than that if you're expecting an answer.

Comment: may be helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064990/android-media-player-error-1-4-while-playing-an-audio-from-assets-folder

Answer (score 6):

The following link explains apparently the cause for the problem:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8624

Answer (score 2):

Is it the 10.1v tab (running 3.0 or 3.1) or an "old" one running 2.2?

According to this: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html you seem to need 3.0+ for H.264 AVC. I have had troubles with H 264 myself even with recommended values, had to downscale the sound even more. Might be worth looking in to.

Answer (score 0):

This link is very helpful me so i would like to suggest to you.

http://android.joao.jp/2011/07/mediaplayer-errors.html

Next thing is that you have `just past your error code` `No Logcat` or `No Java` code without it no body can judge your code.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The error code is -2147483648 which is 0x8000 0000 which is UNKNOWN_ERROR. If you can rebuild the android platform, I feel you could enable logs in `OMXCodec` and `AwesomePlayer` modules by uncommenting `#define LOG_NDEBUG 0`, rebuild and replace the `libstagefright.so`. Based on the error logs, further help could be extended.